# Kafka Stream app goes down when one of the broker goes down and other brokers are running

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

We have a Kafka Stream app using Spring Cloud Stream connecting to 3 brokers with replication factor 3 using AWS MSK.

Now there is a regular patching once in every month where at a time only single broker is down. But the Kafka stream app goes down (SHUTDOWN state) even if one broker goes down and the other 2 brokers are up with exception

> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [AdminClient clientId=blabla] Connection to node 1 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

Can someone guide me to ensure Kafka stream doesnt go down even if other 2 brokers are up during this interval.

Comment: What is your bootstrap server configuration for stream application?

Comment: Hi, I am connecting to 3 brokers at the same time and basically the usual configs like :    streams:
      ssl:
        key-password: ${keyPwd}
        key-store-location: "file:///opt/kafka/certs/kafka.client.keystore.jks"
        key-store-password: ${keystorePwd}
        trust-store-location: "file:///opt/kafka/certs/kafka.client.truststore.jks"

Comment: I think you did not get it. You need to config your stream application with kafka brokers you are connected. How you configure those?

Comment: ok will share as examples too.  spring.cloud.stream.kafka.binder.brokers: <broker1-url>,<broker2-url>,<broker3-url>